# dimple.js - keeping scale after reloading new data

Tags: d3.js

In d3.js I can load a dataset and filter it on 'year'. This opproach gives me the possibility to calculate my d3 scales and vertical axis based on my **complete** dataset's max y value.

My aim is to get the graph to be visually comparable when changing view from one year to another. - With the same maxscale value, and the same relative vertical height per unit in the columns after reloading data for another year.

Do anybody know how to accomplish this in dimple.js?

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't use dimple, but can you just set a fixed axis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation there are some examples of what you're trying to achieve..

Namely, one in which the axis min and max settings are manually set..

```
 // Setting min and max dates requires them to be set
    // as actual javascript date objects
    y.overrideMin = new Date("01/01/2000 9:00 am");
    y.overrideMax = new Date("01/01/2000 6:00 pm");
```

In this case they are Time values for a day, which make sense not to change, but the same should apply.. But, you should give us some of your code examples for more specific answers.

So from chart change to chart change, you will retain the same Min & Max as the previous year.

Reference [DimpleJS Advanced Time Axis](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_time_axis)